# How can I merge CSV rows that have the same value in the first cell?

Tags: python, csv, bioinformatics, jupyter-notebook, libreoffice-calc

This is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5v-nJeoVouHc25wTGdqaDV1WW8/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, there are duplicates in the first column, but if I were to combine the duplicate rows, no data would get overridden in the other columns. Is there any way I can combine the rows with duplicate values in the first column?

For example, turn "1,A,A,," and "1,,,T,T" into "1,A,A,T,T".

Comment: is using `pandas` ok or you're looking for a solution in plain python?

Answer (score 5):

Plain Python:

```
import csv

reader = csv.Reader(open('combined.csv'))
result = {}

for row in reader:
    idx = row[0]
    values = row[1:]
    if idx in result:
        result[idx] = [result[idx][i] or v for i, v in enumerate(values)]
    else:
        result[idx] = values
```

How this magic works:

- iterate over rows in the CSV file
- for every record, we check if there was a record with the same index before
- if this is the first time we see this index, just copy the row values
- if this is a duplicate, assign row values to empty cells.

The last step is done via `or` trick: `None or value` will return `value`. `value or anything` will return `value`. So, `result[idx][i] or v` will return existing value if it is not empty, or row value.

To output this without loosing the duplicated rows, we need to keep index, then iterate and output corresponding `result` entries:

```
indices = []
for row in reader:
    # ...
    indices.append(idx)

writer = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv', 'w'))
for idx in indices:
    writer.writerow([idx] + result[idx])
```

Comment: Thanks, that is an elegant solution. Do you know how I could output that to a csv file without losing the non-duplicated rows?

Comment: @MaxPeart, added to the answer